# Unable to read the project file ".csproj"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I have two project one is a "WCF Application" and other is " Windows Phone Application". When I open the project it shows the following error

> Unable to read the project file 'test.csproj'. 
>   The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Expression\Blend\WindowsPhone\v7.1     \Microsoft.Expression.Blend.WindowsPhone.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the   declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I have already installed **Microsoft Expression Blend 4**. But there is no **"WindowsPhone"** folder. I am not getting which setup is remaining to install. Can someone tell me which setup is remaining ?

Comment: Have you installed the Windows Phone SDK?

Comment: @AlastairPitts  I have solved the problem. I just repair windows phone sdk. Thanks for reply